# Hadoop two node cluster environment, NameNode’s web UI displays the number of live nodes as one and Dead nodes as zero

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I configured properly two node cluster environment for Hadoop, and Master is also configured for datanode as well.
So currently I have two data nodes, without any issue I am able to start all the services in Master.
Slave datanode is also able to stop start from Master Node.
But when I am checking the health by using the url `http://<IP>:50070/dfshealth.jsp` Live node count is always showing only one not two.

Master Process:

```
~/hadoop-1.2.0$ jps
9112 TaskTracker
8805 SecondaryNameNode
9182 Jps
8579 DataNode
8887 JobTracker
8358 NameNode
```

Slave Process:

```
~/hadoop-1.2.0$ jps
18130 DataNode
18380 Jps
18319 TaskTracker
```

Please help me to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please check the datanode logs. It would be in the /var/logs in the datanode which is not able to connect. Please post the logs here

Comment: I checked the datanode logs and got the below error              2014-07-27 15:55:24,205 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: masternode/192.168.157.132:8020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2014-07-27 15:55:24,205 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at masternode/192.168.157.132:8020 not available yet, Zzzzz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution,

After @charles input I checked the Datanode logs and got the below error.

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: masternode/192.168.157.132:8020. Already tried 9 time(s);
```

I was able to do the ssh but there was issue with telnet from datanode to master for 8020 port.

```
>telnet 192.168.157.132 8020

Trying 192.168.157.132...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.157.132: No route to host
```

I just added in iptables to allow the port 8020 by using below command and restarted the hadoop services and everything worked fine.

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp --dport 8020 -j ACCEPT
```

It was the issue with firewall only.
Thanks to all for valuable inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The second DataNode is running but not connecting to the NameNode. Chances are you re-formatted the NameNode and now have different version numbers in the NameNode and DataNode.

A fix is to manually delete the directory where the DataNode keeps its data (dfs.datanode.data.dir) and then reformat the NameNode. A less extreme one is to manually edit the version but for study purposes you can just axe the whole directory.

Comment: It didnt work for me, however after debugging came to know that its firewall issue and added the port number 8020 in iptables to allow access from outside and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, iptables and selinux can prevent communication.